# 2000s book with a human female protagonist who lives with two vampires, one of which is her brother

Tags: story-identification, novel, vampire, werewolf

Vampire book where the protagonist is not a vampire; her boyfriend and brother are. I remember that the brother had a boyfriend and the beginning of the book talks about the brother walking in on them trying to have sex.

They all live together with another couple and their niece -- who is the girlfriend of this blond guy -- turned into a vampire so she wouldn’t die. Then, at some point, there’s werewolves involved and the blond one gets attacked and nearly dies,

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and do you recall anything about the cover?